# Sort Array of Hashes by value from high to low

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I am having a Hash in this format:

```
images_found = {
  "results" => [
    {"img_1"=>1.923076923076923},
    {"img_2"=>0.8241758241758242},
    {"img_3"=>0.6868131868131868},
    {"img_4"=>0.5494505494505495},
    {"img_5"=>0.4120879120879121},
    {"img_6"=>0.3434065934065934},
    {"img_7"=>0.2747252747252747},
    {"img_8"=>0.2060439560439561},
    {"img_9"=>0.1373626373626374},
    {"img_10"=>0.06868131868131869},
    {"img_11"=>0.5494505494505495},
    {"img_12"=>0.3434065934065934},
    {"img_13"=>0.2747252747252747},
    {"img_14"=>0.2060439560439561},
    {"img_15"=>0.1373626373626374},
    {"img_16"=>0.06868131868131869}
  ],
  "type" => "SEARCH_RESULTS"
}
```

I would like to sort `images_found["results"]` by value from highest to lowest, such that the result would be:

```
images_found = {
  "results"=> [
    {"img_1"=>1.923076923076923},
    {"img_2"=>0.8241758241758242},
    {"img_3"=>0.6868131868131868},
    {"img_4"=>0.5494505494505495},
    {"img_11"=>0.5494505494505495},
    {"img_5"=>0.4120879120879121},
    {"img_6"=>0.3434065934065934},
    {"img_12"=>0.3434065934065934},
    {"img_7"=>0.2747252747252747},
    {"img_13"=>0.2747252747252747},
    {"img_8"=>0.2060439560439561},
    {"img_14"=>0.2060439560439561},
    {"img_9"=>0.1373626373626374},
    {"img_15"=>0.1373626373626374},
    {"img_10"=>0.06868131868131869},
    {"img_16"=>0.06868131868131869}
  ],
  "type" => "SEARCH_RESULTS"
}
```

The solution I tried is `images_found["results"].sort_by! {|_key, value| value}` but it is not working.

When I tried to debug `value` it is printing `nil`

I looked around for solutions but didn't find anything that matches with this problem statement.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 4):

it should be

```
images_found["results"] = images_found["results"].sort_by(&:values).reverse
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to get the desired results:

```
images_found["results"].sort_by! { |x| x.values.first }.reverse!
```

Note that method with `!` changes the original hash. If you do not want to change the original hash, remove `!`.

Another option would be to use `-` sign for sorting condition:

```
images_found["results"].sort_by! { |x| - x.values.first }
```

Comment: this `images_found["results"].sort_by! { |x| - x.values.first }` worked like a charm!

Comment: `!` is not an operator.

Comment: Your statement (unfortunately using the term _symbol_ which has other uses in Ruby) still implies `!` is an operator that has an effect on `sort_by`, this is incorrect. `sort_by!` is a different method entirely to `sort_by`. The `!` is a character and part of the method name. Take a look at the documentation. +1 for your second approach though.

Comment: I was just thought of indicating the difference between 2 methods for easy recognition by `!`. If it makes confusion again I will change it.

Comment: Your first result is incorrect. The correct value is returned but `image_found["results"`] is sorted by increasing values of the lone hash value. The problem is that `reverse` does not change the hash in place. You need `reverse!`.

Comment: Nice catch @CarySwoveland